# Nginx rewrite, whe url ends with more then one slash

Tags: regex, web, nginx, url-rewriting

I have some 404 page (example.com/404.html)

I want to forward all requests ending with more then one slash to it

for example

- example.com- valid
- example.com/- valid
- example.com//- invalid, 404
- example.com///- invalid, 404

and so on.

I`m not exeprienced in nginx configuration, so i`l be very grateful for help

Answer (score 1):

You just want to use this behavior for trailing slashes or for double/triple/etc slashes anywhere in the URL?

If you need to do the latter - see [merge_slashes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes). It can disable the slashes merging for whole URL.